# How to use SBOL (Synthetic Biology Open Language)?

Tags: sbol

One of my students is working on the development of a SynBio tool to design and represent genetic circuits in a standardized format. I know there are some libraries out there.

What I am interested in finding out is to have a hands-on tutorial how to use an SBOL library (say, pySBOL) to represent genetic circuits in SBOL data and visual representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pySBOL there is a tutorial you can follow in the [documentation](https://pysbol2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#). Additionally, there is a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtDttQX4_z4) walking through a similar tutorial, note the tutorial starts at about 1:09:00.

There are lots of additional tools and libraries out there such as [SBOL Canvas](https://sbolcanvas.org/canvas/) (for visualisation), [libsbolj](https://goksel.github.io/libSBOLj3/) (a java library for SBOL), and other [libraries](https://sbolstandard.org/libraries/) and [tools](https://sbolstandard.org/applications/) listed on the SBOL website.

Comment: Thanks @PlantPromoter.